# What is wrong with my simple Dash app application that is not causing my plot to work correctly?

Tags: python, flask, plot, plotly-dash

I made a Dash app that graphs Stock Market data from my SQL database. The app uses one input that can have multiple values. For my case, this input strictly only refers to stocks. Hence, users can chain multiple stocks in an input to create a plot with their prices, on top of each other. Using the Flask @callback methods, I am able to do that.

[image: This is how the dashboard looks like]

The graph is not working, the input bar works great and users can select multiple stocks. For sure it has to do with the data that is being passed but I can't locate where and the more I seem to fix it the more it breaks...

Check out my code below:

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.graph_objects as go


import dash_html_components as html

from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate



#PostgreSQL Connection
from connect import *

# CSS
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']



# Pre-load:
stock_ids = execute_query(conn, "SELECT DISTINCT id FROM security_price;")
stock_ids = [i[0] for i in stock_ids]
options = [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in stock_ids]


# Create Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)





# Create app layout
app.layout = html.Div(
                   [    html.Div(className='row',  # Define the row element
                                children=[
                                # left element
                                  html.Div(className='eight columns div-user-controls', 
                                    children = [
                                    html.H2('SP500 Equity Analyzer'),
                                    html.P(''' Compare stocks on your watchlist.'''),
                                    dcc.Dropdown(id="my-multi-dynamic-dropdown", options=options, multi=True, placeholder="Select a Symbol"),
                                    dcc.Graph(id='timeseries', config={'displayModeBar': False}),

                                    ]
                                    ),
                                 
                                  










                                  # right element
                                  html.Div(className='four columns div-for-charts bg-grey'),
                                 





                                 ]),
                   ])


# User callbacks

#user input
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output("my-multi-dynamic-dropdown", "options"),
    [dash.dependencies.Input("my-multi-dynamic-dropdown", "search_value")],
    [dash.dependencies.State("my-multi-dynamic-dropdown", "value")],
)
def update_multi_options(search_value, value):
    if not search_value:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        return [
            o for o in options if search_value in o["label"] or o["value"] in (value or [])
        ]

# timeseries graph
@app.callback(Output('timeseries', 'figure'),
              [Input("my-multi-dynamic-dropdown", 'search_value')],
              [State("my-multi-dynamic-dropdown", "value")],
)


def update_timeseries(input_data, state): 
    if input_data == None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    if state == None:
        raise PreventUpdate
  


    # Draw and append traces for each stock
    trace = []  


    for stock in input_data:  
        stock_info = execute_query(conn, f"SELECT date, close FROM security_price WHERE security_price.id  = '{stock}' ;") 
        for row in stock_info:
            date = []
            adj_close = []

            date.append(row[0])
            adj_close.append(row[1])
        # STEP 2
            trace.append(go.Scatter(x=date,
                                     y=adj_close,
                                     mode='lines',
                                     opacity=0.7,
                                     name=stock,
                                     textposition='bottom center'))  
    # STEP 3
    traces = [trace]
    data = [val for sublist in traces for val in sublist]
    # Define Figure
    # STEP 4
    figure = {'data': traces,
              'layout': go.Layout(
                  colorway=["#5E0DAC", '#FF4F00', '#375CB1', '#FF7400', '#FFF400', '#FF0056'],
                  template='plotly_dark',
                  paper_bgcolor='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                  plot_bgcolor='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                  margin={'b': 15},
                  hovermode='x',
                  autosize=True,
                  title={'text': 'Stock Prices', 'font': {'color': 'white'}, 'x': 0.5},   
              ),

              }

    return figure

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Invalid argument `figure.data[0]` passed into Graph with ID "timeseries".
Expected `object`.
Was supplied type `array`.
```

Alongside this Javascript error from Dash:

```
Error: Invalid argument `figure.data[0]` passed into Graph with ID "timeseries".

Expected `object`.

Was supplied type `array`.

    at propTypeErrorHandler (http://127.0.0.1:8050/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/dash_renderer.v1_8_0m1599348644.dev.js:90547:9)

    at CheckedComponent (http://127.0.0.1:8050/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/dash_renderer.v1_8_0m1599348644.dev.js:84930:77)

    at renderWithHooks (http://127.0.0.1:8050/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@16.v1_8_0m1599348644.13.0.js:14960:20)

    at updateFunctionComponent (http://127.0.0.1:8050/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@16.v1_8_0m1599348644.13.0.js:17193:22)

    at beginWork (http://127.0.0.1:8050/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@16.v1_8_0m1599348644.13.0.js:18778:18)

    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://127.0.0.1:8050/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@16.v1_8_0m1599348644.13.0.js:182:16)

    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://127.0.0.1:8050/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@16.v1_8_0m1599348644.13.0.js:231:18)

    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://127.0.0.1:8050/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@16.v1_8_0m1599348644.13.0.js:286:33)

    at beginWork$1 (http://127.0.0.1:8050/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@16.v1_8_0m1599348644.13.0.js:23369:9)

    at performUnitOfWork (http://127.0.0.1:8050/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@16.v1_8_0m1599348644.13.0.js:22323:14)
```

Would greatly appreciate where my program went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where your problem is coming from:

```py
    # Draw and append traces for each stock
    trace = []  


    for stock in input_data:  
        stock_info = execute_query(conn, f"SELECT date, close FROM security_price WHERE security_price.id  = '{stock}' ;") 
        for row in stock_info:
            date = []
            adj_close = []

            date.append(row[0])
            adj_close.append(row[1])
        # STEP 2
            trace.append(go.Scatter(x=date,
                                     y=adj_close,
                                     mode='lines',
                                     opacity=0.7,
                                     name=stock,
                                     textposition='bottom center'))  
    # STEP 3
    traces = [trace]
```

You've made `trace` a list, and then put that into `traces`, another list. You should put all of the `go.Scatter` objects into `traces`, so that the list contains `Scatter` objects, not sub-lists.

Comment: So I took away `traces = [trace]` , and just made one list instead, called traces. The error is now gone, thank you so much. I seemed to have solved this issue but now I have another where my axis are all wrong.